# How to run CloudFormation Nested stacks from Github?

Tags: github, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Our CloudFormation templates are stored in Github and our AWS pipeline works great when I am using GitHub as a provider to get the Artifacts.
The only limitation is that we have at this point is that we are unable to use **Nested Stacks** as I don't know how to move the code from Github to S3 **automatically** as Nested Stacks expect the templates to be stored in S3.
Really Appreciate if someone could share the code(Lambda) and steps to address this as I am pretty sure this must be an issue with many deployments.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use build stage and use AWS CLI to move the nested stack temeplates to their bucket.

Comment: @Marcin Can you please help me with a sample buildspec.yml file OR what would the command look like to cp the templates to S3 - Thanks !

Comment: It would be just standard [cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) command like you would use on local workstation. Your CodeBuild project's service role would have to have S3 permissions to enable that.